# Why does SGPLOT ignore my `MarkerSymbol` choices?

Tags: sas

I'm creating a `VLine` plot with `Proc SgPlot`, with 4 groups of data. Here is my code to create the plot. (I've genericized the variable names, of course.) This is wrapped in a macro, but I don't think that makes any difference.

```
proc sgplot data=mydata;
    vline NominalTime / Response=responseVariable Group=MyGroups stat=mean markers;
    format MyGroups MyGroups.;
    Where scaleNum=&scaleNum;
run;
```

I'm using Proc Template to customize the line colors, LineStyles, and MarkerSymbols. The Template code is below:

```
proc template;
    define style Styles.MyNewStyle;
        parent = styles.HTMLBlue;
        style GraphBackground / 
            backgroundcolor=white;
        style GraphData1 from GraphData1 / 
            markersymbol = "circle"
            color = CXFFB44B 
            contrastcolor = CXFFB44B
            ;
        style GraphData2 from GraphData2 / 
            markersymbol = "circle"
            color = white 
            contrastcolor=CX000000
            ;
        style GraphData3 from GraphData3 / 
            markersymbol = "Square"
            color = CXD33183 
            contrastcolor=CXD33183
            ;
        style GraphData4 from GraphData4 / 
            markersymbol = 'Square'
            linestyle = 2
            color = white 
            contrastcolor=CX555555
            ;
        style GraphFonts from GraphFonts /
            'GraphDataFont' = ("Arial",11pt)
            'GraphValueFont' = ("Arial",11pt)
            'GraphLabelFont' = ("Arial",11pt,bold)
            'GraphFootnoteFont' = ("Arial",8pt)
            'GraphTitleFont' = ("Arial",12pt,bold);
        end;
run;
```

Of course, I've used `ods html` to change the output style:

```
ods html style=MyNewStyle;
```

Here is the crux of the question: the plot is generated with the colors as specified, but with incorrect `markersymbol` and `linestyle` assignments for groups 2 to 4. Stated another way, whatever `markersymbol` and `linestyle` I specify in `GraphData1` is used for all of the lines in the plot, regardless of later assignments. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
proc template;
    define style Styles.MyNewStyle;
        parent = styles.HTMLBlue;
        style GraphBackground / 
            backgroundcolor=white;
        style GraphData1 from GraphData1 / 
            markersymbol = "circle"
            color = CXFFB44B 
            contrastcolor = CXFFB44B
            ;
        style GraphData2 from GraphData2 / 
            markersymbol = "circle"
            color = white 
            contrastcolor=CX000000
            ;
        style GraphData3 from GraphData3 / 
            markersymbol = "Square"
            color = CXD33183 
            contrastcolor=CXD33183
            ;
        style GraphData4 from GraphData4 / 
            markersymbol = 'Square'
            linestyle = 2
            color = white 
            contrastcolor=CX555555
            ;
        style GraphFonts from GraphFonts /
            'GraphDataFont' = ("Arial",11pt)
            'GraphValueFont' = ("Arial",11pt)
            'GraphLabelFont' = ("Arial",11pt,bold)
            'GraphFootnoteFont' = ("Arial",8pt)
            'GraphTitleFont' = ("Arial",12pt,bold);
        end;
run;

data mydata;
do mygroups = 1 to 4;
do nominaltime=1 to 20;
responsevariable = mygroups*nominaltime;
output;
end;
end;
run;

ods html style=mynewstyle;

proc sgplot data=mydata;
    vline NominalTime / Response=responseVariable Group=MyGroups stat=mean markers;
*    format MyGroups MyGroups.;
*    Where scaleNum=&scaleNum;
run;
ods html close;
```

If that works on your system, then you have a problem with your MyGroups. format or values, I suspect.  What values does MyGroups have natively - 1-4 or something else that MyGroups. format converts to 1-4?

If that doesn't work on your system, give more system details - 9.3, 9.2, etc.?

Comment: I'm using SAS 9.3. My boss and I tried various avenues to fix the issue, but I was only able to change the `MarkerSymbols` by directing to `ODS Listing` instead of `ODS HTML`. I will try to do some more troubleshooting when I have the opportunity, but for right now this workaround will have to suffice. Thank you for giving this question some attention.

Comment: Did my example work on your system, or did that also fail to work?

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I ran the exact code you used and all 4 lines had circles as markers and solid lines. I also used `ods html style = styles.mynewstyle` but got the same (incorrect) result. However, setting `parent = styles.Default` does the job perfectly. I'm not sure why inheriting from a different style makes a difference, but it will work for now. Strangely, I've even seen articles from SAS that show code changing the markers and lines for `HTMLBlue`. Just another SAS oddity I guess.

Comment: Could even be a version difference, maybe you need (or have) a hotfix or somethingl.

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding this behavior is that starting with SAS 9.3, the HTML destination uses the HTMLBlue style by default.  This style is a "Color  priority" style, where only the color is rotated first.  There are 12 defined colors.  So, the first 12 group values get one of these 12 colors, with the first marker symbol and line pattern.  After the first 12 groups, the next 12 groups get the second marker symbol and line pattern, with the 12 colors again.

With HTMLBlue, the other markers and line patterns will only show up after the first 12 group values.

Most other styles have attribute priority of "None".  This means the all three attributes are rotated at the same time.  So first group value gets color 1, symbol 1, and pattern 1.  Second group value gets color 2, symbol 2, and pattern 2 and so on.

With SAS 9.4, the option ATTRPRIORITY was introduced in the Style definition and on the ODS GRAPHICS statement to control this behavior.  Now, you can use this option to make any style rotate the attributes the way you want.  To make HTMLBlue behave like LISTING, use the ODS Graphics option ATTRPRIORITY=none.